# Twilio respond to keypress during voice call

Tags: twilio, esp8266

I am new to Twilio and to programming in general.

I have a simple Arduino based App running on an ESP8266. Basically it rings an alarm on a scheduled basis, and requires the user to press a button to silence the beeping alarm.
If the alarm beeps 10 times, it then places a voice call from Twilio to a specific number and announces "the alarm is ringing".
Everything is working great to that point.

I would like the voice call to say "The alarm is ringing. Press 1 to silence the alarm."

I have no clue as to how to 'accept' the buttonpress . Everything that I can find seems to be about routing internally within Twilio (forwarding, voicemail, etc), but nothing about Twilio posting a response outside.

Any guidance? Any PHP sample code anywhere that does this kind of thing?

Comment: Is the alarm on ESP8266 the one you want to silence with the press 1 on the phone call?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a gather in your TwiML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather timeout="10" numDigits="1">
        <Say>The alarm is ringing. Press 1 to silence the alarm.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes

once the user presses a digit then your server will be hit with another request with the Digits param set, check if it equals 1

Comment: The action attribute might be needed https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#examples-2